# Managing staging and production servers using git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I've just started working on a website that I've inherited from someone who used SVN to manage their code and I want to switch it over to using Git.

I've figured out how to the actual SVN->Git conversion so that's sorted and I'm looking in to how best to arrange the branching to future proof it in case we take on any more developers and have to work in parallel.

However, the part I need some clarification on is the way I should be using Git to work the staging and production servers.

Currently, the process is to put new code on to the staging server using svn update on there. We then do an svn copy to create a new release branch, then an svn switch to use that branch.

When the changes are shown to be working on there, we move to the production code and svn switch to the new release branch in production.

If I want to use git, is it correct to do the following?

1) Make local code changes

```
$ git add <whatever>
$ git commit -m 'Something'
$ git push origin master
```

2) ssh to web server

```
$ cd <staging dir>
$ git pull
```

3) Test changes on staging site

4) Once changes are working

```
$ cd <production dir>
$ git pull
```

?

Or do I need to do a git checkout in there somewhere or something?

Comment: @bodget Looks good, thats how i do it. Maybe you could create a tag for version releases.

Answer (score 0):

I think using separate branches for staging and production is better than relying on when you pulled the master branch to which directory as you get version control over your deployment .

E.g., when you want to go to staging, `git push origin staging`. Then in staging dir,

```
git checkout staging
git pull
```

and when you're satisfied

```
git checkout production
git merge staging
git push
```

(If you're paranoid, verify that it still works) and then

```
cd <production>
git checkout production   #just to be sure
git pull
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - however, I'm not sure what this gives me exactly. In general, the process would be to test all changes on another server (called, say, test) before making those changes to the staging server.

Then, as long as the staging server site looks good, I'd (straight away) go and git pull on the production server.

So what do you mean when you say "relying on when you pulled the master branch to which directory" ?

Comment: I meant that you are not really involving git in the staging -> production step, you could essentially copy or rsync from the staging directory to the production one. I'm not saying that it is wrong, I just think that putting staging and production in their own branches adds a safety net, especially if you work in parallel or distributed. But if you are the only one doing the deployment it may just be overhead.

Comment: ... so git-wise, your suggested workflow is fine, but Rogier already commented on that.
But it doesn't really match your SVN workflow with new release branches, does it?

Comment: Ah OK - got it. Yeah, so that was my next problem really - branching. I don't like the current SVN workflow - I think both the staging and the production servers should be running master, not some random release branch.

Comment: So I was wondering whether using something like git flow would be the best way forward starting from the moment I begin using git? Or do you think that might be overkill for a small operation (with only developer at the moment) ?

Comment: I don't use git-flow myself (although I sometimes have a `stable` branch, and often use feature-branches), but I think it boils down to how firmly organized/versioned your "releases" are. Here is a blog post about why git-flow doesn't fit the way GitHub works: http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69138/discussion-between-bodger-and-srobertz).